# when attr(id) is selected then... jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using a form that picks up the "name" of each field supplied and then sends the information. My problem is I need to join all the checked, check boxes onto this selector and its instead creating a separate one.

```
     HTML

<div class="labSample" >Sample Request*:<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="234kl2j234io2" name="234kl2j234io2" value="Value1">
Value1
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="234kl2j234io2" name="234kl2j234io2" value="Value2">
Value2
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="234kl2j234io2" name="234kl2j234io2" value="Value3">
Value3
<br>

    var data = {};
    f.find('input,textarea,select').each(function(i){
            var tag = $(this);
            var products = [];
            var check = $('234kl2j234io2').attr('name');

            $('input[name="234kl2j234io2"]:checked').each(function(i){
                products.push($(this).val());
                data.check = products.join('; ');

            });

            data[tag.attr('name')] = tag.val();
        });


    $.form(f.attr('data-action'), data, 'POST').submit();
```

Its creating a selector called "check" instead of taking "check" and combining it with the 'name' attr attached to '234kl2j234io2'. '234kl2j234io2' is also the id that is attached to each checkbox so it is only picking up one element instead of 3 ( it has to be an id for each, that is the only way to have the form can be sent ). So I was trying to find a way to bind all the checked checkboxes onto that id so it will identify each instead of just recognizing the last checkbox checked since they are all id's. I was hoping since the data is being sent using the 'name' attribute, I could bind them somehow in jquery.

Comment: `'234kl2j234io2' is also the id that is attached to each checkbox ` Id's have to be UNIQUE in the entire DOM

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: I understand that, but I'm using Salesforce which can only accept one value per ID, so I need a workaround to where I can attach multiple values to one ID

Comment: If you can post your HTML you might get more help

Comment: i updated with the html

Comment: In that case, you could select by type, if it suits you. Like: $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i){....